# Why can't ssh establish "the authenticity of host" for Github?

Tags: git, ssh

Both fingerprints of my host and my key on Github are the same. Why does the connection still fail?

```
ssh -vT  git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wangs/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-        6+squeeze1+github12
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
The authenticity of host 'github.com (204.232.175.90)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ssh client does not know the RSA Fingerprint of the Github server yet, that's why *it asked you* if you want to connect to it.

If you enter yes, the server's fingerprint will be added to your client's list of known hosts and it will not prompt you again unless the server's finger print changes.

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. I thought the defaut answer is yes.So I did not type yes.Actually it is not.Many thanks